# Django: Integrate Permissions and Groups functionality into Custom User Model

Tags: django

I have create a custom user model for my django apps.
Now i want to use the django permissions and groups system. I made permission and groups
but when i go to use them in my custom user model a take errors like

```
>>> john.groups.add(special_users)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MyCustomUserModel' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

I imagine that i have to put some extra code in my custom user model to integrate this functionality
Could anyone help with this problem?

Comment: Does the custom user model inherit from django contrib `User` ?

Comment: It inherit from AbstractBaseUser

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally MyCustomUserModel  had to inherit and from PermissionsMixin

```
class MyCustomUserModel(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
```